# PostgreSQL sequences nextval() strange behaviour

Tags: postgresql

I was testing postgresql sequences (using http://sqlfiddle.com with PostgreSQL 9.3 I dont have a PostgreSQL setup locally at the moment), but I was seeing strange behaviour.

Create a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE counter_seq;
ALTER SEQUENCE counter_seq RESTART 9223372036854775805;
```

Then select the next value fromt the sequence:

```
SELECT nextval('counter_seq');
```

The result was `9223372036854776000` which is outside the range of BIGINT!?!?

The sequence itself seemed to update properly (it would fail after a couple of selects with `ERROR: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "counter_seq" (9223372036854775807)`) but the result of `nextval` was incorrect when it did run.

I then tried setting the sequence to much lower:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE counter_seq RESTART 5223372036854775805;
SELECT nextval('counter_seq');
```

But the result was:

```
5223372036854776000
```

I couldn't get reliable behaviour until I dropped the sequence value to `5000000000000000`.

Is this a postgresql bug or sqlfiddle?

Comment: cant other sessions roll sequence meanwhile?..

Comment: Possibly, but I did test on sqlfiddle with different sequence name and it gave the same exact result. So I suppose it is safe to assume something is broken on their side.

Comment: **counter_seq** seems too common name - If I'm not mistaken - users share same schema there, so I think people are just rolling your sequence ahead

Comment: I have used __counter_seq_s052305migdsgds__ and it gives wrong result as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/025825/1/0

Comment: yes - and I just recalled that it was rexter to share schema, not sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like either SQLFiddle error or pgsql 9.3 issue. I'm not getting the same result on my local 9.6 nor does it give such error on http://rextester.com/COJS32891

Comment: not reproducing on `PostgreSQL 9.3.14 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit`

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński looks like I'll be using rextester from now on

Comment: Yes it looks like an sqlfiddle bug with displaying large numbers, I tried a different example: inserting 9223372036854775805 into a BIGINT field, when you read it back it is incorrect.